# Version of Ubuntu and ROS for NXT and Turtlebot2

Tags: nxt, turtlebot2, turtlebot, ros-hydro, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a configuration for my fall AI/Robotics undergraduate course. I would like to find the best version of Ubuntu and ROS for use on both NXT and Turtlebot2.  Here is my problem:

Currently I am testing Ubunto 12.04 (Precise) with ROS Hydro.  I think this will work fine with Turtlebot, both on the bot and the workstation. But I also want to use Lego Mindstorm NXT to get the students started. It looks like ROSNXT needs ROS Electric, but ROS Electric will not run on Ubunto 12.04.

So, it looks like I might have to go back to Ubunto 10.04 (Lucid) and ROS Electric to get support for ROS NXT, but Turtlebot2 is not supported in ROS Electric (you need Groovy)

So, I don't see a single configuration that supports ROS NXT and Turtlebot 2... Does that seem correct?

```
   -- I could upgrade to Lego Mindstorm EV3 for the fall, if ROS Hydro will support it by September...?  
   -- Should I try building ROS NXT from source under Hydro, but this looks like it has challenges
   -- Is it possible to run ROS Hydro under Ubuntu 10.04? It does not look like it
```

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173011/version-of-ubuntu-and-ros-for-nxt-and-turtlebot2/) by [tgibbons](https://answers.ros.org/users/18810/tgibbons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would lean very strongly towards the newer versions of Ubuntu and ROS; either 12.04 and ROS Hydro or 14.04 and ROS Indigo. Indigo is currently in Beta now, and should be released in about a month.

In general, the core ROS API and build system change very slowly, and it shouldn't be too difficult to get older ROS packages to build with newer versions of ROS. Note that you can still use rosbuild if you're building packages from source on Hydro and Indigo.

A bit of searching turns up a few updates to the NXT stacks since Electric:

- https://github.com/maxsieber/nxt - updated for Groovy
- http://wiki.ros.org/sig/NXT - the NXT SIG. It looks like someone is working on a catkinized version targeted at Hydro, but it's hard to tell if it works or not

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2